# ASP.NET Core 3 React SPA Template - Set AccessTokenLifetime

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0, spa-template

I'm using the latest react SPA .NET Core 3 template and wondering is there a way to set the "AccessTokenLifetime" for a client, where obviously that client is my SPA.

I've been looking here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization.md#application-profiles and I've tried quite a few different things.

But doesn't seem there is a way to set client properties, other than the few detailed on the page above eg RedirectUri, LogoutUri

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of hunting I found that you can do it during the call to `AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();` in the `Startup`

Replace it with:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
    {
        foreach (var c in opt.Clients)
            c.AccessTokenLifetime = 120; // Expiration in Seconds
    });
```

All of the [Token settings for Identity Server](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/client.html#token) seem to be settable here.

Note that the collection of `Clients` is determined by your configuration. In the case of the basic `dotnet net react -o <name> -au Individual` template, the following is in the `appSettings.json` using the name of the project (the `-o` option to the `dotnet` command):

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
        "ReactAppIdentity": {
            "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
    }
}
```

I dug around in the source code but unfortunately I couldn't see a way to set these settings via configuration.